# enable pressing tab to search in google chrome on my website

Tags: google-chrome, search, opensearch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add google chrome omnibox-search support for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site)

I have a question about how to enable the "press tab to search" feature in google chrome for my own website.

I already linked an opensearch.xml document and I have the following included:

`<Url type="text/html" template="http://localhost:3000/?search={searchTerms}"/>`

However this still doesnt work.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is `opensearch.xml` example that works for me:

```
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <ShortName>Example.com</ShortName>
    <LongName>Example.com Search</LongName>
    <Description>Search through Example.com</Description>
    <Query role="example" searchTerms="example search"/>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <OutputEncoding>UTF-8</OutputEncoding>
    <AdultContent>false</AdultContent>
    <Language>en-us</Language>
    <SyndicationRight>open</SyndicationRight>
    <Developer>Example.com</Developer>
    <Tags>tag1,tag2</Tags>
    <Image height="16" width="16" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">http://example.com/favicon.ico</Image>
    <Url type="text/html" template="http://example.com/search.html?q={searchTerms}"/>
    <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="http://example.com/suggestions.html?query={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

I think `localhost` and/or non-standard port `3000` might also contribute to the problem.

Comment: how do you find the url that leads directly to the query box on the target site? (in google translate for instance)